# Generating URL with explode, preg_replace and urlencode

Tags: php, preg-replace, urlencode, explode

I'm trying to build URL with PHP, URL contains non-latin characters (slovenian č, š, and ž).
I'm having some problems because I also need to replace space with `+` and also encode non-latin characters.

What I need to do is change this string `'Knjižnica Bežigrad'` into this:   `'Knji%C5%BEnica+Be%C5%BEigrad'`. So `+` character must not be encoded.

I tried to explode each word in a string (string can also have more than 2 words), then do a do a `preg_replace` (+ instead of space) and finally `urlencode` of each word (but not the `+` character).

I didn't manage to put this approach in working state, maybe there is a better way of doing it?

**Additional explanation:**

If I echo this string like

```
<?php echo $item->title; ?>
```

I get value `'Knjižnica+Bežigrad'`.

If I echo like this

```
<?php echo urlencode($item->title); ?>
```

I get value `'Knji%C5%BEnica+Be%C5%BEigrad'` which is exactly what I need.

But somehow when I construct URL like this

```
<a href="index.php&searchword=<?php echo urlencode($item->title); ?>">
```

string `$item->title` still contains a space instead of a `+` character.

That's way I wanted to use approach which I mentioned above.

Comment: I've just found out that problem is in SEO friendly URLs.
When URLs are generated, + character is converted to %20.

Probably that's whay I'm getting desired result when I do echo on variable.

Comment: Current situation: I'm replacing space with + like this:

`$itemtitle = preg_replace('/\s+/', '%2B', $item->title);

Then I generate link like this <a href="index.php&searchword=<?php echo urlencode($itemtitle); ?>">link</a>

It works in Firefox and Chrome, I get desired URL: index.php&?searchword=Knji%C5%BEnica+Be%C5%BEigrad, but IE renders URL like this: index.php&?searchword=Tržnica+Bežigrad.